# Need help returning random order multiple-choice answers for ms-access test bank

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have an Access2013 multiple-choice test Db that returns test questions in a random order to a form.  This works okay but for each question asked, the answers are displayed in the same order each time.  Each table for this particular Db is set up as:

tblTest (by course)

ID (PK)

Course

Vol

Question NO

Section

Question

Ans A

Ans B

Ans C

Ans D

Correct Answer

I understand this is not optimized data, hence not being able to randomize answers.  Some sites recommended spliting the table, so what I have done now is to create 2 separate tables like so:

tblRnd_Ques

ID (PK)

Course

Vol

Question No

Section

Question

tblRnd_Ans

ID (PK)

Q_ID (FK)

Answer

Correct (Y/N)

I then created queries that randomized both tables by randomizing tblRnd_Ques.ID and tblRnd_Ans.Q_ID, then a query to join both random queries.  What I would like to do is have the question show in the form, then find the answer in qryRnd_Ans and return the answers, in the order they appear in the query.  What will need to happen is show the question, then search through the recordset to find the next related answer and give that as answer # 2, etc.  Each question has a unique ID number and is repeated 4 times throughout the recordset with corresponding answers.

I have searched on several sites looking for ways to do this, to include using FindNext, etc.  I am quite the novice with VBA and cannot figure out how to get it to do what I need.  Here is the code I use (thanks to help from stackoverflow previously) to return each question:

```
Private Sub LoadNextQuestion()   'reusable code to load questions

rcdCnt = rcdCnt + 1

    If (rcdCnt > 100) Or rsCourse.EOF Then
        GetQuestionTotal
        LogTestResults
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rptResults_Test"
        rsCourse.Close
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmIntro"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmQues"
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryEmptyQuestions"
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryEmptyResults"
        DoCmd.CloseDatabase

    Exit Sub
    End If

With rsCourse
    intQues = !ID
    strCDC = !CDC
    intVol = !Vol
    strSect = !Section
    strQues = !Question
    strAns = !Answer
    blnCorr = !Correct

    ctlQ_No = rcdCnt
    ctlQuestion = !Question
    ctlSection = ![Section]

 MsgBox intQues & _
    Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "CDC:  " & strCDC & _

    Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Volume:  " & intVol & _

    Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Section:  " & strSect & _

    Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Q:  " & strQues & _

    Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "A:  " & strAns & _

    Chr(13) & Chr(10) & blnCorr

    ctlAns_A = ![Answer]
'        ctlAns_B = ![Ans B]    (Commented out for testing purposes)

'        ctlAns_C = ![Ans C]    (Commented out for testing purposes)

'        ctlAns_D = ![Ans D]    (Commented out for testing purposes)

    strSect = ctlSection
    strCorrectAnswer = ![Correct]
    optAnswer = Null   'clears previous answer
    optAnswer.SetFocus

    .MoveNext

End With
End Sub
```

I assume I may need a subform for the answers, but have no idea how to get both the question and the answers to generate properly.  Any assistance I can get is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You have separate question and answer tables for each course? Why not just one questions table with another field for CourseID? And then just one answers table?

Comment: I have two tables. tblRnd_Ques contains the courses (which would be another way of stating CourseID and all the questions. tblRnd_Ans has the answers and whether each is correct or incorrect.   Now, I could create another table strictly for the course number, but wouldn't that just add another complication to the code?

Comment: Okay, 2 tables, not dozens. Sounds okay.

Comment: However, the tables you describe are not for purpose of saving responses. Those two tables can be used in a report/subreport to print a questionnaire. Saving responses will require another table with fields for UserID, QuestionID, AnswerID. Have a main form bound to Users and a subform for the Responses table. Now the question is how will the recordset for user/questions/responses be created in the Responses table? Is the goal to have responders input their responses directly to database?

Comment: Yes, the two tables shown above are strictly to create the test/questionaire.  I do have another table called tblResults, which records the individual names (taken from another form), as well as the course taken, total questions answered, score, date and time.  As far as their responses, these are only kept in a volatile recordset, and this recordset is emptied at the end of the test.  Your comments have both been on point.  Sorry if I didn't fully describe the Db I am using.

Comment: So do you really need a form arrangement that will allow users to input reponses?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using Rnd() function in query ORDER BY clause. Randomize answers on ID, not Q_ID. Then use subform/subreport container Master/Child Links to synchronize records. I tested and did not need any VBA. Use those tables in report/subreport arrangement to print a questionnaire. Not seeing how it is useful to display those tables in a form/subform with randomized order. You would want this form/subform if adding new questions and answers to the test bank, not for user responses.

Comment: Here is the SQL I currently have for the answer table:  SELECT Rnd([ID]) AS Rnd_ID, tblRnd_Ans2.ID, tblRnd_Ans2.Q_ID, tblRnd_Ans2.Answer, tblRnd_Ans2.Correct
FROM tblRnd_Ans2
ORDER BY Rnd([ID]);      I know this reply doesn't look pretty, but I can't figure out how to add a carriage return in the comments.

Comment: You can edit your question to provide additional info. Don't really need Rnd(ID) in the SELECT clause, just in ORDER BY. Did you try suggestion? It worked for me.

Comment: Yes, it would be much easier to print the questionnaire, however, we are using this strictly as computer-based.